# Is it necessary to protect the lifetime of objects inside a closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

The following code will create 2 clients and connects to the server. The life time of socket variable is expected to live till the end of the program. Although the code works fine, just wondering, Is it necessary to add the **socket** variable inside the closure to an array or some container outside the closure in order to protect the lifetime of the **socket**.

```
var usernames = [];
usernames.push('tom');
usernames.push('bob');

usernames.forEach(function (username) {

    var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000', {'forceNew': true});

    socket.emit('loaded', {username: username});
}
```

Comment: It doesn't protect the lifetime of the socket, it just protects the ability to access it. The socket will stay open as long as it should, but if you don't expose it, you can't access it

Comment: How does the javascript know how long is "AS LONG AS".

Answer (score 0):

from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-websockets-20110419/#garbage-collection):

> A WebSocket object whose readyState attribute's value was set to CONNECTING (0) as of the last time the event loop started executing a task must not be garbage collected if there are any event listeners registered for open events, message events, error events, or close events.
>
> A WebSocket object whose readyState attribute's value was set to OPEN (1) or CLOSING (2) as of the last time the event loop started executing a task must not be garbage collected if there are any event listeners registered for message events, error events, or close events.
>
> A WebSocket object with an established connection that has data queued to be transmitted to the network must not be garbage collected. [WSP]
>
> If a WebSocket object is garbage collected while its connection is still open, the user agent must close the WebSocket connection. [WSP]

Comment: So does that mean that node makes a special exception to the **socket** object according to the WebSocket.

Comment: differentiate between the socket's connection, the socket's object and the handle to the object. whether you want to keep a handle or not depends on your needs; think of the spec as addressing browsers, not you. it is saying "don't garbage collect if there are event listeners, an open connection, etc". but obv browsers don't always implement recommendations so you might want to test this.